# Setting the default pulseaudio capture source to "monitor" via command-line

Tags: linux, command-line, pulseaudio, recording

I want to do this from commandline:
[image]

What I've done so far is to create a `~/.asoundrc` file with the following contents:

```
pcm.pulse_monitor {
  type pulse
  device alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
}

ctl.pulse_monitor {
  type pulse
  device alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
}
```

With `alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor` as the desired monitor source.But it doesn't work because if I launch **Audacity** and set the source to `Built-in ...` via **pavucontrol** and then relaunch the Audacity the default source would be still `Builtin ...` not `Monitor of builtin ...`

Is there any way to make it work in command-line ? Note that restarting the pulse-audio server is not preferred because it would cut the sound of all the current clients of the PA server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**analog-stereo.monitor** is a Pulseaudio source for audio recording. It would not be recognised by ALSA when used in file ~/.asoundrc

to see information about Pulseaudio sinks and sources, including defaults:

```
pacmd dump
```

**default-source** for recording can be set with:

```
pacmd set-default-source alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
```

it may also help to remove `Built in Analog Stereo` as a recording option so only `Monitor of Built in Analog Stereo` is available

(`pavucontrol` will not show a drop-down list of sources if there is only one available for recording)

pacmd data probably shows the **card-profile** as:

```
set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
```

change it to output only with:

```
pacmd set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 output:analog-stereo+input
```

Card profile can also be changed in GUI using `pavucontrol -t 5` Configuration tab

change profile in drop-down menu from *Analog Stereo Duplex* to *Analog Stereo Output*